# Is there a way to mix different datatypes in UNION select statement

Tags: sql

I have a `UNION ALL` select statement like:

```
SELECT 'First' as definition, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as cnt
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' as definition, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as cnt
FROM mytable1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' as definition, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as cnt
FROM
mytable2
```

The cnt column is an INTEGER, what is clear.

The output looks like:

| Definition | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| First | 750 |
| Second | 852 |
| Third | 230 |

What I want as output should be:

| Definition | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| First | 750 |
| Second | 852 |
| Third | - |

I tried it with the statement:

```
SELECT 'First' as definition, CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS STRING) as cnt
FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' as definition, CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS STRING) as cnt
FROM mytable1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' as definition, '-' as cnt
FROM mytable2
```

This is working as it should, but the problem is that afterwards all of the numbers are datatype STRING.
I want to have the datatype INT for all of them, because the numbers should be with thousand separator and alligned right at the front end later. This is only possible if they have datatype INT.

Is this possible in any way, that although I mix STRING and INT to get INT datatypes in the end?

Comment: `'-' as cnt` => `NULL as cnt`

Comment: You can format the data as you want (with thousand separators, etc) when you cast as string. However you can’t right-align strings. And no, you can’t define values in the same column as having different datatypes

Comment: @LukaszSzozda thanks this works perfect. Have not thought of this very simple solution. ;-)

Comment: And you don't even need to name the columns from 2nd and 3rd selects. The 1st select decides the column names.

Comment: The issue is that there's no integer value `'-'`. You can replace it with a null, maybe, as stated by @LukaszSzozda

Comment: You could simply cast the counts to text.  since - is text and the counts as text would be text.  then they are the same data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `-` (string) a `NULL` value could be used:

```
SELECT 'First' as definition, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as cnt  FROM mytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' as definition, COUNT(DISTINCT ID) as cnt FROM mytable1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' as definition, NULL as cnt                FROM mytable2;
```